# Класс-фабрика в python

Tags: python

Вот есть у меня вот такой занятный класс-фабрика:

```
class Fabric(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Fabric, self).__init__()
        self.queue = deque()

    def DoActionOne(self):
        print "one"

    def DoActionTwo(self):
        print "two"

    def AddActionToQueue(self, action):
        pass

    def ExecuteActonsFromQueue(self):
        pass
```

который должен выполнять действия в произвольной последовательности. Особый интерес, разумеется, представляют два последних метода. Конечно, можно сделать решение "в лоб" — создать константы, символизирующие каждое действие и остальное решение строить от этого. В случае, когда действий становится не два, а косой десяток, код постепенно превращается в индусский.

Есть ли какое-нибудь изящное решение данной проблемы?

Comment: @jfs, преобразуйте, пожалуйста, это в ответ, я приму его.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зачем нужны константы, методы можно или напрямую хранить (функции/методы в Питоне являются объектами, как и всё остальное), или по именам обращаться (`getattr(self, name)` вернёт тогда сам метод). Питон не Джава, лучше избегать [создания фабрик билдеров по созданию менеджеров по управлению фабриками и т.д.](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?joel.3.219431). Кстати, fabric -- это ткань/структура (здания), фабрика -- это factory. [Вот код, который создаёт меню динамически и выполняет сценарий на основе данных из файла](http://ideone.com/I3T3wq).

Answer (score 1):

[@Montreal](/users/11712/montreal), я так понял, вы хотите отделить логику создания класса (вызовы методов, сеттеров, аргументы конструктора) отделить от конструктора и, эм, места создания класса. В этом случае могу порекомендовать посмотреть, как это сделано в [Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html):

- Есть общий контейнер-билдер; фабрикой его, наверное, сложно назвать, потому что он понятия не имеет, что производит (да и не сказать, что производит в классическом смысле - сохраняет в себе), кроме того, что это сервисы-одинчоки.
- Есть типовые действия с инстансом свежесозданного класса - arguments (аргументы для передачи в конструктор, можно ссылаться на другие сервисы в контейнере), calls - вызовы методов, которые должны вызваны после создания класса, properties - список свойств, которые должны быть проставлены после создания.
- Это позволяет один раз конфиг-файлом задать конфигурацию контейнера и забыть про него, позволяя доставать из него сервисы с помощью lazy load.

В вашем случае можно реализовать аналогичную штуковину, которая, правда, будет воспринимать параметры конфига не как сервисы-одиночки, а просто как конфигурацию создания класса, и создавать их при каждом обращении. Или просто добавить в конфиг флаг, который будет делить классы на создаваемые каждый раз и на сервисы. А при наличи аргументов, которые высчитываются только в рантайме, можно добавить еще один ключ конфига, который эти самые методы будет помечать как "передаваемые в рантайме" и требовать их при создании.